# Computing the Quadratic residue

Tags: number-theory

Given that $a$ is a quadratic residue $\pmod p$ where $p$ is prime is there a way to efficiently compute $x$ without enforcing any constraints on $p$ such that :

$$ x^2 \equiv a\pmod p $$

Comment: There are a number of good algorithms. Popular ones are variants of [Tonelli-Shanks.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonelli%E2%80%93Shanks_algorithm)

Comment: If $p \equiv 3 \bmod 4$ you have $x = \pm a^{(p+1)/4}$

Comment: You seem to ask for "general purpose." As pointed out by Cocopuffs, $p\equiv 3\pmod{4}$ can be done by binary method of exponentiation. There is a similar procedure for $p\equiv 5\pmod{8}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As was said in the comments, one method for solving this problem is the [Tonelli-Shanks Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonelli%E2%80%93Shanks_algorithm).

Comment: Therfore if I have $n = pq$ can I find a quadratic residue $\pmod n$ given the fact I can find $R_1^2 \equiv a\pmod p$ and $R_2^2 \equiv a\pmod q$? Can I combine these two in a solution $\pmod n$ ?